# single client send to the multiple server, but the second server not receive the message

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

My OS is linux.I program socket in C.I'm a newwork-programming newbie. Today, I want the single client to write the message to the multiple servers, so I open the two terminals to represent the two servers.But the first server is right, and the second server is still waiting the message from the client.At the same time, the client is over.Therefore, the first server read the message which the client send to the server.I have no idea that what happened.

the client.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <netdb.h> //hostent
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define NAMEMAX 4096
int socket_desc;
int packet_num;
struct timeval timeout;

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
        sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &packet_num);
    //printf("packet_num = %d\n", packet_num);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0L;
    sscanf(argv[4], "%ld", &timeout.tv_usec);
    //printf("timeout.tv_sec = %ld, timeout.tv_usec = %ld\n", timeout.tv_sec, timeout.tv_usec);
        //Create socket
        socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    //printf("socket_desc = %d\n", socket_desc);
    int j = 5;
    int t;
    int isip = 1;
    while(j < argc){
        //int new_socket
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        //server_object server;
        char hostname[NAMEMAX] = {0};
        uint16_t portnum = 0;
        int meet = 0;
        int k;
        for(k = 0; k < strlen(argv[j]); k++){
            if(argv[j][k] == ':'){
                //portnum = argv[j]+(k+1);
                meet = 1;
                t = (k+1);
                continue;
            }
            if(meet == 0){
                hostname[k] = argv[j][k];
                if(isdigit(argv[j][k]) || argv[j][k] == '.'){
                    isip = 1;
                }
                else{
                    isip = 0;
                }
            }
            if(meet == 1){
                portnum = portnum*10 + (argv[j][k] - '0');
            }
        }
            char ip[100];
        memset(ip, 0, sizeof(ip));
            struct hostent *he;
            struct in_addr **addr_list;
            int i;
        struct in_addr hipaddr;
            if(isip){
            inet_aton(hostname, &hipaddr);
            he = gethostbyaddr(&hipaddr, 4, AF_INET);
        }
        else{
                he = gethostbyname( hostname );
        }
        //Cast the h_addr_list to in_addr , since h_addr_list also has the ip address in long format only
        addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
            for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++){
                //Return the first one;
                strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
            }

            //printf("%s resolved to : %s\n" , hostname , ip);
        //strcpy(server.server_ip, ip);
        //printf("port = %u\n", portnum);
        //server.server_portportnum;
            server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip); 
            server.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server.sin_port = htons(portnum);
        //thread start
        //pthread_t ntid;
        //pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, request, &server);
        struct timeval start;
        struct timeval end;
        struct timeval thistimeout = timeout;
        int num = 0;
        //Connect to remote server
            int test_con = connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
        //printf("test_con = %d\n", test_con);  
            //puts("Connected\n");
            //Send some data
        //while-loop begin
        //int overtime = 0;
        while(((num < packet_num && packet_num != 0) || (packet_num == 0)) && thistimeout.tv_usec >= 0){
            char msg[200];
            memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            //strcpy(msg, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
            sprintf(msg, "%d", num);
            long diff;
                gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
            printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
            ssize_t write_s;
            write_s = write(socket_desc, msg, sizeof(msg));
            printf("write_s = %ld\n", write_s);
            //printf("write_s = %ld\n", write_s);
            //printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
                //puts("write failed");
            assert(num <= INT_MAX);
            //Receive a reply from the server
            char buf[2000];
            //printf("readbef\n");
            ssize_t read_s;
            read_s = read(socket_desc, buf, sizeof(buf));
            printf("read_s = %ld\n", read_s);
            //printf("readafter\n");
            //printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
            gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
            diff = 1000000 * (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+ end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
            thistimeout.tv_usec -= diff;
            //printf("thistimeout.tv_usec = %ld\n", thistimeout.tv_usec);
            //printf("thedifference is %ldmsec\n",diff);
            //printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
                //puts("Reply received\n");
            printf("recv from %s:%u, seq = %s, RTT = %ld msec\n", ip, portnum, buf, diff);      
            fflush(stdout);
            num++;
        }
        if(thistimeout.tv_usec < 0){
            printf("timeout when connect to %s:%u, seq = %d\n", ip, portnum, num);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        close(socket_desc);
        sleep(1);
        j++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

the server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int sv_socket_desc;

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    int new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;     
    //Create socket
    sv_socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0); 
    //printf("sv_socket_desc = %d\n", sv_socket_desc);
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    uint16_t portnum;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%hu", &portnum);
    server.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    //server.sin_port = htons( 8888 ); 
    //Bind
    bind(sv_socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
    //Listen
    listen(sv_socket_desc , 3);     
    //Accept and incoming connection
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while(1){
        new_socket = accept(sv_socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        printf("new_socket = %d\n", new_socket);
        //puts("Connection accepted");         
        //Reply to the client
        struct sockaddr_in newclient;
        //start thread
        ssize_t read_size = 0L;
        ssize_t write_size = 0L;
        char client_message[200];
        memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));
        unsigned short int client_port_num = ntohs(newclient.sin_port);
        char client_addr[2000];
        //inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(newclient.sin_addr.s_addr), client_addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("00\n");
        char *clientIP = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
        while(read_size >= 0){
            //(read_size = read(sv_socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message))) >= 0
            //printf("readbef\n");
            //printf();
            read_size = read(new_socket, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
            printf("read_size = %ld\n", read_size);
            //fflush(stdin);
            //printf("read_size = %ld\n", read_size);       
            //printf("client_message = %s\n", client_message);
            //fflush(stdout);
            write_size = write(new_socket, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
            if(read_size){
                printf("recv from %s:%hu, seq = %s\n", clientIP, client_port_num, client_message);
            }
            //printf("recv from %s:%hu, seq = %s\n", client_addr, client_port_num, client_message);
            memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("01\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        //Free the socket pointer
        close(new_socket);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using threads together with `select()`?  The point of the latter is to provide for multiplexing I/O so that you can *avoid* multi-threading and multiprocessing.  If you use threads then there's no reason to avoid blocking I/O, since the threads have nothing else to do while they're waiting, anyway.

Comment: Looking further, you're not getting any benefit from your threads anyway, because you join each one before starting the next one.  I think you're making this too complicated.  I suggest getting it working serially first: let the client call `request()` directly, rather than creating a separate thread to do so, and let that function perform ordinary blocking I/O without relying on `select()`.

Comment: Also, be sure to close each connection when you're done with it.  You appear not to do so.

Comment: should I take off the thread on the client ?

Comment: and then close connection on the client after each server is sended over?

Comment: *should I take off the thread on the client?* -- yes, that is what I have suggested.  Get rid of both the multithreading and the `select()`.  Make the client perform all communication with one server, then move on to the next.  That might be altogether sufficient already, but if not, then it will be a more stable starting point for a version in which the client distributes messages to multiple servers.

Comment: I have gotten rid of the thread and the select on the client, just as you say. But the problem still exists. I think the problem should come from the server.

Comment: Inasmuch as the server software operates as you expect on one machine, it seems likely that if it does not work correctly on another then the client has some contribution to that.

Comment: In any event, the next step would be to check the return values of your function calls for error codes, both in the client and in the server.  Robust software must do this consistently, and must provide appropriate handling when errors are detected.  "Appropriate handling" might be as simple as calling `perror()` and then exiting.

Comment: oh no! I got the new problem. The server cannot read.

Comment: I have debugged the new problem, but the old problem still exist.

Comment: Consider editing the code currently in your question into a [mcve] based on your revised code.  I no longer have any idea what code we're talking about, plus, the process of trimming it down to an MCVE may help you discover the problem for yourself.

Comment: finally, I place the client's socket in the while loop, and then it can work normally. TKS!!